# Python: Why is 0x01 an integer?

Tags: python, windows, integer

The following:

```
print(type(0x01))
```

Returns:

```
<class 'int'>
```

Whereas, the following:

```
print(0x01)
```

Returns

```
1
```

Now let's say we have:

```
x = "0x01"
```

How do I convert x such that it returns 1 when printed?

Thank you!

Comment: `int(x,16)` ... will convert using base16

Answer (score 1):

You would need to convert using base 16 as suggested by @Joran Beasley

```
x = "0x01"
print(x)
x = int(x, 16)
print(x)
```

Returns:

```
0x01
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually 0x01 is an hexadecimal format which is base16 so to convert it to decimal format you need to use int() method as shown below

```
x ="0x01"
x = int(x, 16)
print(x)
```